# Change width of valueBox in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, width, shinydashboard

I'm creating value boxes like this:

```
valueBox(value = tags$p(winterMean, style = "font-size: 70%;"), 
                   subtitle = tags$p("Mean Winter Performance \u20ac / MWh", style = "font-size: 90%;"), 
                   color = "black")
```

Which yields the following `valueBox()`:

[image]

The color black is defined in th `ui.R` file like this:

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(".small-box.bg-black { background-color: #007d3c !important; color: #FFFFFF !important; }")
)
```

How can I change the width of the `valueBox` to the red line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `valueBox()` and `valueBoxOutput` functions have a `width` argument (Using the bootstrap grid system from 1 to 12, see section "Layouts" [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#layouts)):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Value boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      # A static valueBox
      valueBox(10 * 2, "New Orders", icon = icon("credit-card"), width = 2),
      
      # Dynamic valueBoxes
      valueBoxOutput("progressBox", width = 2),
      
      valueBoxOutput("approvalBox", width = 2)
    ),
    fluidRow(
      # Clicking this will increment the progress amount
      box(width = 4, actionButton("count", "Increment progress"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$progressBox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste0(25 + input$count, "%"), "Progress", icon = icon("list"),
      color = "purple"
    )
  })
  
  output$approvalBox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "80%", "Approval", icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon"),
      color = "yellow"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]